# Array got flushed after while loop within a filehandle

Tags: arrays, perl, filehandle

I got a problem with a Perl script.

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = ('a','b');

if(@data){
  for(@data){
    &debug_check($_)
  }
}

print "@data";#Nothing is printed, the array gets empty after the while loop.

sub debug_check{
  my $ip = shift;
  open my $fh, "<", "debug.txt";
  while(<$fh>){
    print "$_ $ip\n";
  }
}
```

Array data, in this example, has two elements. I need to check if the array has elements. If it has, then for each element I call a subroutine, in this case called "debug_check". Inside the subroutine I need to open a file to read some data. After I read the file using a while loop, the data array gets empty.

Why the array is being flushed and how do I avoid this strange behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: `if(@data){ for(@data){ ... } }` is a unnecessarily complex way of writing `for(@data){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here I think, will be down to `$_`. This is a bit of a special case, in that it's an *alias* to a value. If you modify `$_` within a loop, it'll update the array. So when you hand it into the subroutine, and then `shift` it, it also updates `@data`.

Try:

```
my ( $ip ) = @_;
```

Or instead:

```
for my $ip ( @array ) { 
     debug_check($ip);
}
```

Note - you should also avoid using an `&` prefix to a sub. It has a special meaning. Usually it'll work, but it's generally redundant at best, and might cause some strange glitches.

Comment: even if it weren't passed to the subroutine, the while loop (shorthand for `while ( defined( $_ = <$fh> ) )` would still be changing the array values (because the for aliases $_ to them).  Using variables other than $_ in *both* the for loop and the while loop would be a good idea (though just changing the for fixes this problem)

Comment: Thanks very much. I just changed all default variables for defined ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<$fh>)
```

is short for

```
while (defined($_ = <$fh>))
```

`$_` is currently aliased to the element of `@data`, so your sub is replacing each element of `@data` with `undef`. Fix:

```
while (local $_ = <$fh>)
```

which is short for

```
while (defined(local $_ = <$fh>))
```

or

```
while (my $line = <$fh>)   # And use $line instead of $_ afterwards
```

which is short for

```
while (defined(my $line = <$fh>))
```

Be careful when using global variables. You want to localize them if you modify them.